# Change deployment slot for published API App in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing Web API project published as a 'API App' on Azure.  I recently added a "staging" deployment slot that I'd like to publish future versions of the API App before Swapping over to production.  However, if I try to create a new publish profile in VS 2015 (or 2017), all my Web Apps are listed except the API App - so there is no way to select the existing deployment.  Put this another way, if I delete the publish profile I have no way to publish the project using the Publish wizard (unless I download the publish profile from Azure, but I still have no way to change the deployment slot - that I know of).

[image]

I can see my API App in Cloud Explorer OK.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to go to "deployment slots" in your web app click on a staging slot and then on the right side you will have your staging blade and then ou can download publish profile that is specific to staging slot:

[image: Deployment slot]

[image: Deployment slot publish profile]

Comment: Perfect - should've of thought of that!  Really it should work from the VS Publish Wizard IMO, but this works great, and it's not as if I will be doing it very often.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your first screenshot, we could find that there are multiple **resource groups** in current subscription, but you just check the API App in resource group ***InergySystemsMain***, please make sure if the API App belongs to other resource group.

Besides, as RAS said, we could download publish profile of Azure app service from Azure portal to local, and then we could import this publish profile file in Visual Studio.

[image]